# What is this weird JavaScript syntax that seems to mix HTML tags with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have seen an interesting peace of javascript code, but don't understand what does it mean and why it returns me an error when I try to test it in console.

Here is an example of code:

```
const Component = ({name}) => (<div>Hello {name}</div>)
```

Is it something acording to the ES6 or what?

PS: I guess I can use it in a render function in this way:

```
<Component name={'John'} />
```

Right?

Comment: here you have JSX and you cannot test in console

Comment: Yeah, that's JSX. It's used by JS frameworks like React. It needs to be transpiled in to real JavaScript before running it in your browser.

Comment: You may want to use these keywords: "React functional component" and "ES6 parameter destructuring".

Comment: `({name}) => (<div>Hello {name}</div>)` this is a fat arrow function, please search for google, its an `ES6` style

Comment: I'm using react-native run-ios, but it show me an error. I thought it could transform JSX to JS

Comment: to your last question, yes u can then use it inside render, in the end its what react calls a functional stateless component https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Vladu Ionut pointed out -> it looks like a jsx return (Hello {name})
So probably its out of an react Application...

anyway to your question:
const is ES6
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

(foo) => {"bar"}
is an arrow function with parameter foo which returns "bar"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

({name}) => ...
destructuring assignment -> an object gets passed as param, it will just get name from the object and pass it to the function instead of the full object.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

as Vladu Ionut pointed again correctly this can't be used directly in your browser cause your browser probably won't support it thats why you have to transpile it before with e.g. Babel
https://babeljs.io

Comment: I'm using react-native run-ios, I guess it does the same as Babel does or not? @MarcelD

Comment: run-iso will probably create the bundle (which does the transpiling for you) before start the simulator and run the app...
not sure if it transpiles it to js, should be rather C/C++ code - but not sure tbh...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test the JSX syntax in the browser console.

The JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)` function so the compiler(I think for your case is Babel) will transform the jsx into a JS code ( Take a look here--> https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/) .

Answer (score 0):

This is not plain javascript. This is JSX code, which is specific to the [ReactJS framework](http://reactjs.org/).
Typically this code is found in a file with a .jsx extension. If you setup a ReactJS development environment, this code will be compiled (or [transpiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931479/compiling-vs-transpiling)) from JSX to plain javascript.

[ReactJS.org](http://reactjs.org/) recommends you use the [Babel compiler](https://babeljs.io/), but note that just compiling your code fragment won't work outside of a full react setup.