# Compiling vs Transpiling

Tags: compiler-construction, abstraction, transpiler

While searching about the difference, I came across these definitions:

**Compiling** is the general term for taking source code written in one language and transforming into another.

**Transpiling** is a specific term for taking source code written in one language and transforming into another language that has a similar level of abstraction.

I understand what Abstraction is.

But what does "similar level of abstraction" mean in the above definition? And how do we find the level of abstraction in a language?

Comment: Is this the source? https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2012/11/compiling-vs-transpiling/

Answer (score 353, accepted):

The definition you have quoted above is too general for a beginner to understand completely and so let me just simplify it to something we see practically.

**Compiler:** is an umbrella term to describe a program that takes source code written in one language and produce a (or many) output file in some other language.
In practice we mostly use this term to describe a compiler such as gcc which takes in C code as input and produces a binary executable (machine code) as output.

**Transpilers** are also known as source-to-source compilers. So in essence they are a subset of compilers which take in a source code file and convert it to another **source code file** in some other language or a different version of the same language. The ouput is generally understandable by a human. This output still has to go through a compiler or interpreter to be able to run on the machine.

Some examples of transpilers:

1. [Emscripten](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/): Transpiles C/C++ to JavaScript
2. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/): Transpiles ES6+ code to ES5 (ES6 and ES5 are different versions or generations of the JavaScript language)

Now, what do they mean by "similar level of abstraction":
As I said it compiles/transpiles to a source file, one can argue that assembly language is also a source file and thus gcc is also a transpiler. So, this argument is what this similar level of abstraction voids.

The notion of categorizing languages into lower, middle and higher level is based on the level of abstraction they provide from the actual working of the machine/architecture.

Lower level languages like assembly are very close to the processor architecture i.e. have different instructions for different processors. While C/C++/Java/JavaScript, abstract all this away providing more abstraction.

So, a transpiler compiles to a language that is closer to the language you started with in the terms of this abstraction (or is closer to the level of that language in the lower-middle-higher level language ladder).

Comment: "Some examples of transpilers:" --- babel calls itself a compiler. The separation between transpilers and compilers is really artificial.

Comment: @zerkms As I said, transpilers are a subset of compilers.

Comment: I'd like to add one thing, we are talking about natural language here. Thus fuzzy definitions is expected. I would expect the "ease of reading" the output of a transpiler to be similar to what it was before while a compiler makes things harder to read. Thus Webpack/npm is a compiler, you don't want to read it's output. (At least when you add the "Loaders" for e.g. .vue files.

Comment: Opinion: I posit that the definitions should be: Compilation: language -> lower level language. Transpilation: language -> same level language.

Comment: @Deji Not necessarily same level-language, but a language at a similar level of abstraction.

Comment: With regards to the answer by @tapananand there might be at least 2 models concluding all said above : 

- model A : superset is transpiled to its set (JSX by babel to vanilla JS)
- model B : some set compiled to its subset (some programming codebase to machine code, _not mentioning intermediate representation [IR] for some virtual machine optimisation or relevant_)

Answer (score 84):

Here's a sort of descriptive way to answer

If you think of layers of abstraction as this example:

```
(1) CPU-level (actual logic gates on the CPU)
(2) machine code
(3) assembly code
(4) [C/C++, JVM/bytecode]
(5) [JavaScript, Python]
```

A compiler goes to a lower level (lower number). A transpiler switches from one language (or version of a language) to another at the same number.

Comment: Curious, where that list of "abstraction levels" came from?

Comment: Just random illustrative examples, I know the first two are kinda mushy tbh, but I wanted a longer list :P

Comment: I like it and it would be really cool if it was some "official" classification like that. Since without it it's hard to put a tool (a translator) into one or another category. Eg: is `javac` a compiler or not.

Comment: `C/C++, JVM/bytecode` makes no sense, 4 should just be bytecode and C/C++ should be in 5. JVM is a runtime environment, not code.

Comment: byte code goes at the 5 level., not the 4 level.

Answer (score 8):

Ex: TypeScript ( a Microsoft superset of JavaScript with type safe checking) transpiles to JavaScript code which can run on different types of browsers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_TypeScript
"Microsoft TypeScript is an open-source programming language developed and maintained by Microsoft. It is a strict syntactical superset of JavaScript, and adds optional static typing to the language.

TypeScript is designed for development of large applications and transcompiles to JavaScript.[5] As TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, existing JavaScript programs are also valid TypeScript programs. TypeScript may be used to develop JavaScript applications for both client-side and server-side (Node.js) execution."

Comment: There is the "typescript compiler" (or tsc) tool, its naming implies that TypeScript is _compiled_ not _transpiled_... yet the tool converts TypeScript to Javascript, which are the same level of abstraction wrt the underlying hardware.  Is TypeScript compiled, or transpiled?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan TypeScript is COMPILED, because it is a superset of javascript, and as such gets compiled down to javascript.

Comment: @Araymer Do you understand the difference between compilation and transpilation?  Because TS is not compiled; nor is JS.

Comment: Yes, I do. And because TS is a superset of JS, it is considered a higher level of abstraction, and therefore is referred to as "compiled". The compiled JS then gets interpreted as normal. Hence why if you look up TS, the single most discussed topic is its "compilation". But, the line between transpilation and compilation doesn't have an official quantitative definition. It gets pretty mushy, so your opinion on what's compiled (differing from the creators, as it is) is just your opinion.

Comment: Microsoft writes that the TypeScript compiler transpiles TypeScript source code to JavaScript: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_transpile-typescript-into-javascript

Answer (score 3):

I mostly agree with tapananand answer, but...

---

#### definition

Words are "made", so they serve a purpose. And this also changes with time.

We now tend to use transpiler to specify a compiler that translates code into some other code "more similar" to the source one, that what a compiler might do. And is used to differentiate both mostly when both of them are mentioned in the same context (again mostly implying that a transpile language will have to get compiled at least once more)

---

#### examples

So everything is *very* subjective. At the time of this writing:

- Coming from the Java world I could call CoffeeScript/TypeScript transpilers to depict that the resulting code is no more efficient than the original one.
- CoffeScript [documentation](https://coffeescript.org/#transpilation) says it's a compiler, and babel is a transpiler. The want do say that CoffeeScript, although very similar, is not Javascript. At least not a version of it, as that is what babel produces.
- [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) calls itself a compiler.

---

#### fazit

So *transpile* is at this time very rarely used anymore, and only to tell two compilers apart.

It will probably dissapear as concept, since compilation is much more complicated than that (same/higher/lower language, version, etc), and the word doesn't seem to be useful anymore ("transpilers" are now ubiquitous)

Answer (score 0):

**Meaning of "similar level of abstraction"**

Higher level languages are more abstracted than lower level languages. By abstracted I mean easier to understand.

**Higher level language**(highly abstracted)---- Similar level -----> **Higher level Another language**(highly abstracted) 
*(TypeScript Source code to JavaScript Source code)*

**Mid level language**(poorly abstracted) ---- Similar level-----> **Mid level language**(poorly abstracted)

**Higher level language**(highly abstracted) ---- Not Similar level of abstraction -----> **Mid level Another language**(poorly abstracted)

Answer (score 0):

**Computers only understand 1s and 0s:** You can think of computer as being a box, crammed full of switches - kinda like a light switch: they can either be "on" or "off" - they can either be a "1" or a "0".  You can instruct a computer which switches you want on or off, with a series of "1s" and "0s".

**People need programming languages:** Human beings are not very good at reading/understanding hundreds of thousands of lines of "1s" and "0s"........ but we can be trained to understand human words: like: `class` and `break`.

Programming languages allow us to write computer instructions, which can be translated into 1s and 0s (compiling), or which can be translated into other programming languages. for example: if you have `elm` code, you can easily transform that into javascript (`transpiling`).

Answer (score -1):

The word "*pre*‎processor" often used as synonym for "transpiler".

The word "preprocessor" was already well-known in the 90th and emphasises that something is processed *before* something else. It is also used in a context of removing comments before code is compiled.

The word "transpiler" became more popular in the 2010th (I heared it first 2015 from a colleague with contact to AngularJS community), calling the process of bringing TypeScript to JavaScript as "transpiling" - as some kind of *trans*‎lation that is like a com‎*pilation* (checking data-types etc.).

To sum it up:

- "Transpilation" fits best when something is translated with some compilation-like functionalities.
- "Preprocessor" is a more generic term where basically something is processed before.

Answer (score -4):

**Compilers** are used to compile source code written in one language to another. A compiler will often use the same syntax as the input language, but it may also be designed for some other type of input, like bytecode.

**Transpilers** are different because they translate code from one programming language to another. The original program may have been written in JavaScript, but the transpiler converts it into HTML.