# Runtime Error - Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]

Tags: php, mysql, ionic3

I'm using this example to understand the operation between ionic and php with mysql
But I find that this error appears to me and I do not understand where it comes from.
The strange thing is that when I load a note it works and it is loaded into the database.

Error
[image]

He left the repository in case they want to visualize the code
https://github.com/javazika/ionic_crud_php_msqyl

[image]

Console
[image]

Comment: Does the console show anything else? Can you show us the code you were working?

Comment: This shows me in the console there I added it @Script47

Comment: Use `ionic serve` to run your application.

Comment: Is running and no error appears

Comment: That is how you are supposed to test your application on desktop. The typescript needs to compile and `ionic serve` compiles it.

Comment: @deceze although that is an error in the console, it isn't the cause of OP's error.

Comment: @Script47 What is then? The request fails, the associated promise rejects, the rejection is uncaught.

Comment: @Script47 So ... when I want to test the application, do I have to test it based on what I compiled?
When I try it from the compiled if it is working.
I do not understand why it does not work directly when running from "ionic serve"
What is different?

Comment: @deceze From your dupe, would the OP find the answer of running `ionic serve`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the [`ionic serve`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/serve/) command through CMD / Terminal while in your project directory.

This [transpiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931479/compiling-vs-transpiling) your TypeScript and builds your app to make it runnable on your device, as per the description from the documentation:

> Start a local dev server for app dev/testing
>
> Easily spin up a development server which launches in your browser. It watches for changes in your source files and automatically reloads with the updated build.

It has live-reload capabilities built into it so you can edit the code on-the-fly and see those changes, once you make a change, look in the console, it should say rebuilding / compiling. That is the TypeScript being [transpiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931479/compiling-vs-transpiling) (again) to JavaScript.

Once you run the command it'll open up a port on localhost and automatically open your app in the browser.

Comment: Thank you! I already understand a little better the functioning of ionic.
and thanks add @deceze
`<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>`
and the console error disappears